# PostgreSQL add EXCLUDE constraint on alter table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to add an EXCLUDE constraint to one of my existing tables this is the sql I'm running:

```
ALTER TABLE appointment_service
  ADD COLUMN start_time bigint,
  ADD COLUMN end_time bigint,
  EXCLUDE USING gist (
            professional_id WITH =,
            int8range(start_time, end_time) WITH &&
  ),
  ADD COLUMN professional_id text REFERENCES professionals ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

And this is the error I get.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXCLUDE"
LINE 4:   EXCLUDE USING gist (
```

What is the correct SQL syntax to accomplish this?

Comment: @Jonast92: you are wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the exclusion constraint separately.

First add the columns:

```
ALTER TABLE appointment_service
  ADD COLUMN start_time bigint,
  ADD COLUMN end_time bigint,
  ADD COLUMN professional_id text 
     REFERENCES professionals ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Then add the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE appointment_service
  add constraint unique_professional_id
  EXCLUDE USING gist (
            professional_id WITH =,
            int8range(start_time, end_time) WITH &&
  )
```

Comment: BTW in single statement it also possible: `create table t(x int); alter table t add column y text, add constraint foo exclude (y with =);`

Comment: @Abelisto: if I try that I get *ERROR: column "start_time" does not exist*

Comment: Hmmm... Seems that it is related to the function usage. `EXCLUDE (       professional_id WITH =, start_time with =);` works.